# Code Snippet Improvement for database call in .NET

Tags: .net, dispose, sqlconnection

Can I get a list of issues with the code below, and fixes?

```
 string ProgramID = HttpContext.Current.Session[CommonFunctions.myNGconnectSessionVars.ProgramId].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyNGConnectDashBoardConnectionString"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;
                cmd.CommandText = "dsb_GetSubscriptionDetailsForSubscriber_ForValidations";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GPCustomerID", strGPCustomerID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", strUserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"].ToString());
                //code changed by sushma 3/22/2011 as new tab added for reach
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgramID", CommonFunctions.ProgramID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgramID", ProgramID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsTeacher", blnIsTeacher);
                // cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

            return ds;
```

Comment: Is the answer "Stored Procedures"?

Comment: Issue 1: this isn't a code review site. Issue 2: we're not here to do your work for you. Issue 3: there's not even a please in there.

Comment: Or perhaps I could answer: '42'?

Comment: @Chris: my impression is that "please" is generally considered noise on SO.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman not when someone is asking me to do their work for them.

Comment: @Chris: yeah, not defending the lame question. "Can I get a..." is a bit of an affront to politeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some immediate improvements

Use `using` statement rather than try/finally for the connection management

Use `throw` and not `throw ex` to re-throw the exception, better yet you can just remove the catch and re-throw

There is no need to call `Parameters.Clear` on the command that you just instantiated.

And finally, if you are going to do a lot of DB work, I would suggest you look at using a lightweight ORM.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue that I can see is that you are not disposing disposable objects such as connections, commands, adapters, ... so in case of exception you might leak resources. To fix your code wrap all disposable resources in `using` statements:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyNGConnectDashBoardConnectionString"].ToString()))
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;
    cmd.CommandText = "dsb_GetSubscriptionDetailsForSubscriber_ForValidations";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GPCustomerID", strGPCustomerID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", strUserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"].ToString());
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I have also removed the `try/catch` block as you don't seem to be doing anything useful in the `catch` statement other than altering the stack trace which is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Except:

> ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"]

Maybe be a little slow when called hundreds of times and

> strUserName

you are fired for using hungarian notation when strondly discouraged for the last 10 years?

And that:

> cmd.CommandTimeout = 900;

Ah - no. 900 seconds? What the heck do you think you do there that needs that?

> cmd.Parameters.Clear();

Yeah. Like this is needed on a new object.

> DataSet ds = new DataSet();

And i fire anyone in general who uses datasets ;) Except in a general query tool where that thing geos straight to the UI.

Not a lot - well, also that we dont realyl do homework reviews here. And I rather would not use a useles try/catch instead going to USING statements.

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly one construct, I want to comment on:

- Don't use `throw ex` - it will alter the StackTrace of ex. Use `throw;` instead.
- Leave away the catch-Block. You can simply use try-finally
- Use two using statements for `con` and `cmd`

Some other points:

- use self-explanatory variable names
- Put the change history into the version control system (and remove it from the comments!)
- Let the source control system handle old code instead of simply commenting it out
- Cache your DB-connection
- Use SqlConnection.CreateCommand